# Ways to control the IsEnable property of a button according to some other variables within a class?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml, binding

I essentially have a problem where I have some button's who's IsEnabled porperty needs to be controlled based on some other variables/properties within the class.

So in the XAML I might have:

```
<Window x:Class="RoboticPainterGUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RoboticPainterGUI"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded" Name="Window_Main"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="555" Width="630">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="Button_Next" Content="Lorem Ipsum" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And in the code-behind for this I might have:

```
namespace RoboticPainterGUI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int A, B;

        bool ButtonEnabledProp
        {
            get
            {
                return ((A + B) >= 5);
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

So, what the behavior I want is as follows:

> When the sum of A and B is 5 or more,
>   the button should be enabled.  When it
>   is less than 5, the button should be
>   disabled.

The `ButtonEnabledProp` has been written already to aid in this process.  How can this be implemented other than manually setting the button's state at every part in the code where A and B are changed?

Binding to a converter would be nice, but the converter wouldn't have access to A or B.
Binding to the property itself would be nice, but I don't know how to do this and haven't found an example how.

Answer (score 1):

You should make MainWindow implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and call OnPropertyChanged, with "ButtonEnabledProp" as property name:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int A, B;

    bool ButtonEnabledProp
    {
        get
        {
            return ((A + B) >= 5);
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        A = B = 3;

        NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonEnabledProp");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could modify your xaml file to add databinding to it, and have something like:

```
<Window x:Class="RoboticPainterGUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RoboticPainterGUI"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded" Name="Window_Main"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="555" Width="630">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="Button_Next" Content="Lorem Ipsum" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ButtonEnabledProp}"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code I've just pasted would make your button to be enabled.

If you want to automate your process, there is no easy way. But [PostSharp](http://www.emidee.net/blog/index.php/post/2010/09/01/%5bPostSharp%5d-Fire-INotifyPropertyChanged.OnPropertyChanged-for-read-only-properties-depending-on-other-properties) does this very well.

Hope this helps

Comment: Better yet, declare A and B as properties and call NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonEnabledProp") in *their* setters - then the binding will be re-evaluated every time A or B changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use binding, you better put this property on another class rather than on the view itself.

So:

- Create a class (ViewModel)
- Add this property to the class
- Add the binding for the View on the IsEnabled of the button
- Set DataContext of the View to an instance of the ViewModel
- Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise `PropertyChanged` event when condition is **changed**.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Rule is the same.